# Conditional Variance of a linear combination

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let X,Y be two R.V. Is the following correct?

$Var[aX+bY|Y]=Var[aX|Y] +Var[bY|Y]+2Cov[aX,bY|Y]$?

Where $Var[bY|Y]=0$.

Comment: The condition at the end $Var(bY|Y)=0$ makes almost no sense - true only if $b=0$, or $Y$ constant.

Comment: Sorry, but if Y is given, what is the variance of Y?

Comment: By def we have: $Var[Y|Y]=E[(Y-E[Y|Y])^2|Y)]$, but if $E[Y|Y]=Y$...

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, then you cannot make such a statement.  All you can write is $$\operatorname{Var}[a X + b Y \mid Y] = a^2 \operatorname{Var}[X \mid Y].$$  There is no further simplification possible because the dependence of $X$ upon $Y$ is not specified.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $$\operatorname{Var}[a X + b Y \mid Y] = a^2 \operatorname{Var}[X].$$

Comment: In my formula, actually I did not use the fact that they are independent. Where did I do that? Moreover, is it true that $Var[bY|Y]=0$? and why the covariance term disappear (while it appears when we do not condition for Y)?